# AspectJ and Java8 - bad type on operand stack

Tags: aspectj, java-8, load-time-weaving

Looking at [This Eclipse Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421307) it seems the Java Verifier (since 1.6) has had issues with ApsectJ.

The bug says AspectJ 1.8.1 will fix the problem.  But using that with Java8u11 I still get the verify error.

I'm running JUnit4 under STS 3.6.0 (Eclipse 4.4).  I believe this configuration is the very latest available of all packages.

Completely replaced the remainder of text with requested example.  This seems to be limited to @Around advice.  **@Before works fine.**

JUnit:

```
package com.test.aspectjdemo.junit;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.test.aspectjdemo.domain.AspectTarget;

public class AspectTargetTest {

    @Test
    public void testFirstMethod() throws Throwable {
        AspectTarget aspectTarget = new AspectTarget();
        aspectTarget.firstMethod();
    }
}
```

Vmarg: -javaagent:C:....m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.1\aspectjweaver-1.8.1.jar

Class under test (I had some problems because proceed apparently declares it throws Throwable, which makes sense, but this simple test didn't throw anything.  So I added a faux exception make it compile :

```
package com.test.aspectjdemo.domain;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class AspectTarget {

    final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    int x = 1;

    public void firstMethod() throws Throwable {
        logger.info("Start First Method");
        x = secondMethod(x);
        logger.info("Exit X is {}", x);
    }

    private int secondMethod(int x) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("input is {}", x++);
        if (x==100)
            throw new RuntimeException();
        return new Integer(x);
    }
}
```

The Aspect:

```
package com.test.aspectjdemo.aspects;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

public aspect LoggingAspect {

    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();


    /**
     * Exclude JUnit methods
     */
    @Pointcut("!within(com.test.aspectjdemo.junit..*Test)")
    public void noJunit() {}


    @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.aspectjdemo.domain.*.*(..)) && noJunit()")
    public void allMethods() { }


    @Around("allMethods()")
    public Object allmethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable   {

        return joinPoint.proceed();

    }
```

Finally once again the Error, which is actually thrown when the JUnit attempts to instantiate the AspectTarget (first line of testFirstMethod method).

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/test/aspectjdemo/domain/AspectTarget.secondMethod(I)I @23: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to integer
  Current Frame:
    bci: @23
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/test/aspectjdemo/domain/AspectTarget', integer, integer, 'org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint' }
    stack: { 'com/test/aspectjdemo/domain/AspectTarget', integer, 'org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint', 'com/test/aspectjdemo/aspects/LoggingAspect', null, 'org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 1b3d b200 4b2a 2a1c b800 51b8 0057 4e2a
    0000010: 1c2d b800 6601 2db8 006a b800 6dac     

    at com.test.aspectjdemo.junit.AspectTargetTest.testFirstMethod(AspectTargetTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Yeah sure, I know what to do next: Please provide a minimal code sample, both Java class and aspect, enabling us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah I knew better than to not have sample code. And creating the sample I learned that it only affects an @Around joinpoint.  It never pays to be lazy.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you mix native AspectJ syntax (`public aspect LoggingAspect`) with annotation-style @AspectJ syntax. I can reproduce the problem this way.

**Correct @AspectJ syntax:**

```java
package com.test.aspectjdemo.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Pointcut("!within(com.test.aspectjdemo.junit..*Test)")
    public void excludeJUnit() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.aspectjdemo.domain.*.*(..)) && excludeJUnit()")
    public void allMethods() {}

    @Around("allMethods()")
    public Object allmethods(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**Correct native AspectJ syntax:**

```java
package com.test.aspectjdemo.aspects;

public aspect LoggingAspect {
    pointcut excludeJUnit() :
        !within(com.test.aspectjdemo.junit..*Test);

    pointcut allMethods() :
        execution(* com.test.aspectjdemo.domain.*.*(..)) && excludeJUnit();

    Object around() : allMethods() {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: HUH! It's sort of amazing my way worked at all.  Thank you very much!